# Що означає слово "скочусі"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У цьому ж збірнику, що подавала у попередньому питанні, "Колядки та щедрівки / Вступ, ст. О. Дея. – Київ: Наук. думка, 1965", є вкінці колядки "Гой ти, наш пане, пане Іване" такі рядки: "У тебе жупани, як у пана, А кунтуші, як скочусі".

У [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46058&page=1455)
знаходжу, що таке кунтуш:

> **КУ́НТУ́Ш**, ку́нтуша́, діал. КО́НТУШ, а, ч., іст. Верхній розпашний чоловічий і жіночий одяг заможного українського і польського населення XVI–XVIII ст.

Щодо скочусі, то тут немає, бо ще нема доповнення до словника, а от у СУМі-11 такої статті взагалі нема.

Отже, що може означати слово **скочусі**?

Comment: Так, важко знайти достовірне джерело, лиш можна припускати, що не є чудовим рішенням. Наприклад, я уявляю таке собі дїєслово _скочу сі_. Але, звісно, це взагалї безʼарґументовано.

Comment: Так, спершу я теж про це подумала, проте не зовсім добре виходить у контексті, адже тут подано як порівняння: жупани такі, як носить пан, кунтуш - ...? А якщо підставити скочу сі, то вийде: верхній одяг - як скочу сі. А це дещо не логічно ніби.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mečislav Krhoun у своїй праці [Koledy](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/121018/SpisyFF_185-1973-1_12.pdf?sequence=1), порівнюючи колядки, зібрані Федьковичем і Гнатюком зазначає:

> Některé rozdíly jsou nápadné, např. u Feďkovyče „В тебе шуби соболеві, Горностаї королеві" — u Hnaťuka „У тебе шуби соболевії, А горностаї коралевії", u Feďkovyče „А жупани як у пана, **А контуши всі в кожусі**" — u Hnaťuka „У тебе жупани як у пана, А **контуші, як скочусі**", u Feďkovyče: „В тебе лани, як загаї, В тебе хліби, як Дунаї" — u Hnaťuka  „У тебе лани, як загаї, У тебе хліби, як тихий Дунай". Hranostaj totiž muže být královský, ale ne korálový, podobně kontuš může být lemován kožišinou, ale obrat „**контуші, як скочусі**" *nedává smyslu*.
>
> ---
>
> *<sup>Приблизний переклад:</sup>*
>   Деякі відмінності помітні, напр. у Федьковича «В тебе шуби соболеві, Горностаї королеві» — у Гнатюка «У тебе шуби соболевії, А горностаї коралевії», у Федьковича «А жупани як у пана, **А контуши всі в кожусі**», у Гнатюка — «У тебе жупани як у пана, А **контуші, як скочусі**», у Федьковича «В тебе лани, як загаї, В тебе хліби, як Дунаї» — у Гнатюка «У тебе лани, як загаї, У тебе хліби, як тихий Дунай». Горностаї можуть бути королівськими, але не кораловими, також контуш може бути вишитий хутром, але оборот «**контуші, як скочусі**» *не має сенсу*.

Оскільки, значення слова  **скочусі** немає  в словниках, то цілком можна погодитися з думкою вищезазначеного автора, і висунути припущення, що можлива помилка (неточність запису збирача, бо записи того часу — «від руки», а не аудіо чи відео; можливо, помилка респондента) у фольклорному тексті, записаному Гнатюком. Можливо, цей рядок мав би звучати так як у Федьковича **«А контуши всі в кожусі»**. 
Щодо «Колядки та щедрівки / Вступ, ст. О. Дея. – Київ: Наук. думка, 1965», то Олексій Дей є лише упорядником, тобто він міг брати тексти з різних збірників, виданих раніше і обрав, той варіант твору, який був записаний Гнатюком (або іншим збирачем).

Comment: Доволі цікаво, дякую!